# Email CSS template framework?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-email, zurb-ink

Anyone know of any email template CSS framework. I am currently using bootstrap, it works, but not exactly built for email. I have looked at "zurb ink" but it just doesn't seem very developer friendly, so hard to make it work. What are others using out there?

Comment: Confirmed for zurb being terrible. Their templates out of the box do not work in Outlook at all.

Answer (score 15):

Check out [MJML](https://mjml.io). It's a framework solely designed to create responsive emails. Similar to Ink in concept I think.

Answer (score 9):

Most email templates use tables and inline styling to be compatible across as many different clients as possible.

Campaign Monitor have some that you can download for free and work with to find one that works well for you: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/all/

Answer (score 7):

Check [Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/), which includes a 12-column grid, as well as some simple UI elements for rapid prototyping.

Ink is developed by the Zurb who also developed one of the popular CSS framework [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

You may check some responsive email templates built on Ink [here](http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but from conversations and random readings it seems like tables and images (i.e. old style "styling") seems to be the way to go with email because a lot of the CSS emails are nto compatible in Outlook

Comment: Yea agree, I understand the use of tables vs div containers when it comes to emails. Zurb ink follows that principle. But I was more looking into email CSS framework options, since I am a developer and not good at CSS.