# How to use bootstrap in laravel mail template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am tried more then 20 times to getting button with href using bootstrap in mail tamplate but it not give right output.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-success">Yes</a>
```

Comment: I think you are not allowed to link styles in mail template. You need to set the style in the old school way: raw css in head section

Comment: thank for your suggestion..why bootstrap not supporting in mail template..??

Comment: @manix Even `<style>` tags are not supported by some email clients. Inline styles is the only safe way to go.

Comment: @dhamodharan you might want to have a look at [Laravel Mail CSS Inliner](https://github.com/fedeisas/laravel-mail-css-inliner). That should inline only the necessary styles from the bootstrap css for each element.

Comment: thank you @manix Even ..that's help me..

Comment: Take a look at [markdown mail](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/27)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it appears that Gmail does not support link or style tags ANYWHERE in the HTML. This is getting seriously annoying

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the link tag in most of the emails. Because not many email clients support this, best to just forget it. I guess you need to put the CSS in there raw. Example:

```
<style>
    // All the bootstrap css
</style>
```

But I recommend (if you want to do it your own way) to style your own button, this way there will be less data in your email template.

```
<button type="button" style="background-color: red;">My button</button>
```

**EDIT**

Best to use an email css/framework template, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474710/email-css-template-framework) question

Comment: it is possible to use bootstrap less in mail template..??

Comment: @dhamodharan I updated my answer, maybe you could use something like that.

Comment: i don't know.. i am just ask you..thank you for your answer that's save my times..